# Magento Override getPrice()

Tags: magento, overriding

I have overrode the price rule of Magento product by overriding the `getPrice()` method in  "`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`" class, simple products are working fine and show the updated price which I mentioned in `getPrice()` i.e

```
    public function getPrice($product)
    {
      return 80;
    }
```

But in the case of downloadable products it shows the original price,
Any one here can tell me how can I override price in downloadable products.

Thanks

Comment: Also the same problem exists in configurable and group products

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that this will be chased down to the getFinalPrice method of Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Price. Trying editing the file to return an obscure fixed amount and see if that's the value you get. If it is then you will need to overload this model too.

Comment: In Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Price  I hard coded the $finalprice to 40, but it does not display 40, instead it shows the same old price