# Override Magento GetPrice function

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I have a custom SQL database in which we have stored different prices per customer per product and per quantity.

Now we want to setup a Magento web store and found out that we cannot really import those prices into Magento because it does not match in terms of data structure. (And Magento would probably melt down because of the huge amounts of data we whould throw at it.)

So I'm thinking; can I leave the data where it is, setup a service on top of that data, and just override some GetPrice() method within Magento to get the right price? (That right price should then of course show up in every possible page that shows prices. And, even more important, that price should be used in baskets and orders too.)

My question is A: Would it work like that? Just overriding one method and we have custom pricing? Or do we have to alter many more methods?

And B: Where can I find that code/method to override?

(Magento is quite new for me. And did spend half a day looking through tons of source code, but i'm not yet that confident with the whole application that i could anwers my own questions by looking through the code.)

Comment: are you   want to assign  customer group wise

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. But no, i'm not looking for a way to assign prices to customer groups. I have a db with prices for each specific customer.

Comment: might want to try over here http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803042/magento-override-getprice but I haven't voted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this for a few clients. This is totally doable.

First you should try to have data on the same server and fetch results live.
If the tables are well indexed (on `product_id` for instance) load time is quite acceptable.

I usually use the observer approach, as it is less intrusive than overriding a catalog model method.

So to do that, create a module and configure an observer in config.xml :

```
</global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <productloadhandle>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Yourcompany_Customprices_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>getCustomPrice</method>
                </productloadhandle>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_load_after>
        <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <getfinalpricehandle>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Yourcompany_Customprices_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>getCustomPrice</method>
                </getfinalpricehandle>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
    </events>
</global>
```

Then create the observer model that will implement the `getCustomPrice` method.

```
class Yourcompany_Customprices_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function getCustomPrice($observer)
    {
        // If not logged in just get outta here
        if (! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            // THis is where you will want to have your price mechanism going on.
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId() == $someIdFromCustomModuleTable && otherConditions) {
                $product = $event->getProduct();
                if ($product && null != $product->getSku()) {
                    // This is where you can tweak product price, using setPrice or setFinal
                    $product->setFinalPrice($customerPrice);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I wont get into details of the rest of the module which is quite standard and that you can find in any **Create magento custom module tutorial**, but that should get you started.

Comment: What is your opinion about overriding vs observing events, performance wise? As Christoffer mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: I dont think there will be any difference. Depends on what you will do in your observer or override anyways. I always tend to prefer using observers cause it allows easy and clean "plug" of code to change Magento behavior but wont have to rewrite entire portions of core code (when overriding you need to rewrite the whole method). If Magento upgrades, you wont have to redig into your rewrites to fit with the potential changes. And finally overrinding is always a pain when several modules want to change the same method: you'll have to introduce dependencies, and this is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Hi baoutch, we have used this to get the right price on the product detail page, and that works perfectly well! But, now I was trying to do the same thing with the prices that are shown in the search results / catalog list. But i cannot find what to observe. Do you know where i can find that?

Answer (score 1):

You should override Mage_Catalog_Model_Product getFinalPrice(). In the overridden method you need to call your web service for price depending on customer group and quantity.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1)** Observe the event `catalog_product_get_final_price` which is fired in multiple product models and different getPrice methods. Probably much easier than trying to override the methods one by one.

**Option 2)** Override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_afterLoad()` and manually set any data variables, like `$this->setFinalPrice($price)`.

*Pros:* Most likely way faster then events. Custom logic runs once at product load, not at every call to getFinalPrice().

*Cons:* Look out for other modules that might already have extended the class.